# how to change images when clicked 2~3 toggle buttons together

Tags: flutter, dart, toggle, togglebutton, image-load

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmkxE.jpg
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmkxE.jpg)
how to change images when clicked 2~3 toggle buttons together
this is what I want to make.
9cat pictures included  in the example.

I want to load cat images( total 9 cat images) //clicked room1 button,cat1button -> load cat1 image // room1button,cat2button - > load cat 2 image ...  clicked room3, cat3button -> load cat 9 image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Fu5.jpg)
enter code here

```
import '123.dart';
import '456.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('imageToggle'),),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: Image.asset('images/meow.jpg')),
            Button123(),
            Button456(),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Button123 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Button123State createState() => _Button123State();
}

class _Button123State extends State<Button123> {
  List<bool> isSelected = List.generate(3, (index) => false);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 40,
      child: ToggleButtons(
        isSelected: isSelected,
        color: Colors.black,
        fillColor: Colors.grey,
        children: [
          Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
          child: Text('room1'),),
          Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
            child: Text('room2'),),
          Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
            child: Text('room3'),),


        ],
        onPressed: (int newIndex) {
          setState(() {
            for (int index = 0; index < isSelected.length; index++) {
              if (index == newIndex) {
                isSelected[index] = true;
              } else {
                isSelected[index] = false;
              }
            }
          });
        },

      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check your question well the image is not showing

Comment: I cannot load image..

Comment: put your image in a list then declear a int var=0 then use it with the index of the assest image then set state to the index